# Cannot send message without a sender address

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm making updates on a laravel-5.6 project that used the make:auth scaffolding. It is unable to send emails on password reset. I have made the required configs in the .env file but still unable to send emails.

**.env file**

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

**config/mail.php file**

```php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],

];
```

I did a `dd($message->getFrom())` in `send()` in `vendor\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php` and the output shows an empty array.

I need help on how to solve it.
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: can you add the error you're having and the code you're writing ?

Comment: if you change the MAIL_DRIVER to "log", will it add the message to your logs instead? The issue could be elsewhere, e.g. mail queue not being processed.

Comment: i'm using the default code that comes with the ```make:auth``` scaffolding for the password reset @N69S

Comment: Are other emails sent out? Is it only the password reset email that is not sent?

Comment: I did the change for the MAIL_DRIVER to "log" and this what i see in log file ```[2020-01-06 08:33:18] local.ERROR: Cannot send message without a sender address {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Cannot send message without a sender address at C:\\apache\\htdocs\\choptime\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:198)
[stacktrace]```

Comment: @EdwinKrause That's the only function using emails for now

Comment: you could try debugging further where the value was "lost" by dumping value of env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS') and config('mail.from.address')
Also be aware if you are testing your mail flow by executing your test suite, laravel will use .env.testing (if available) instead of your .env file.

Answer (score 4):

Try checking your mail settings in .env, specifically the `MAIL_PORT` and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`, if those are wrong it may possibly trigger this error.

**Note:** Check if you've edited .env file, you have to restart the terminal if you're using "artisan" to run your application. (In Laravel ^8 it restarts automatically)

Once you have updated your .env make sure you clear the cache with:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Are you using mailtrap?

Answer (score 0):

I found the `AppServiceProvider.php`'s `boot()` has been set to override the mail configs within the application settings. So it doesn't load the mail configs found in the `.env` file but rather from the application settings.